# How to change the element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirements but I need to use the XSLT. However, I am not familiar in doing the XSLT. I found many solutions on how to change the element name but I don't see any references which is similar to my requirements.

**REQUIREMENT:** I need to change the element name **`<FormDataElement>`**

- if the value contains NUMERIC, then the element tag will become **`<NumericField>`**
- if the value contains TEXT, then the element tag will become **`<TextField>`**
- if the value contains CHOICE, then the element tag will become **`<Choice>`**

**OUTPUT FILE:**

```
<eCDFDeclarations xmlns:ecdf="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
<FileReference>000000B00000000T00000000</FileReference>
<eCDFFileVersion>aaaa</eCDFFileVersion>
<Interface>a</Interface>
<Agent>
    <MatrNbr>001</MatrNbr>
    <RCSNbr>2436</RCSNbr>
    <VATNbr>LU1223434235</VATNbr>
</Agent>
<Declarations>
    <Declarer>
    <MatrNbr>001</MatrNbr>
    <RCSNbr>2436</RCSNbr>
    <VATNbr>LU1223434235</VATNbr>
        <Declaration language="FR" type="AB" model="DIDL">
            <Year>2000</Year>
            <Period>0</Period>
            <FormData>
                <FormDataElement id="233">1NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="234">1NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="235">31TEXT</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="236">12TEXT</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="012">5010,00NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="204">1CHOICE</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="205">0CHOICE</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="414">90,00NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                <FormDataElement id="415">300,00NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                <Table>
                    <Line num="2">
                        <FormDataElement id="01">01/01/2012NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                        <FormDataElement id="02">31/12/2012NUMERIC</FormDataElement>
                        <FormDataElement id="03">EURTEXT</FormDataElement>
                        <FormDataElement id="639">54606,08TEXT</FormDataElement>
                        <FormDataElement id="640">0CHOICE</FormDataElement>
                    </Line>
                </Table>
            </FormData>
        </Declaration>
    </Declarer>
</Declarations>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<ecdf:eCDFDeclarations xmlns:ecdf="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
<ecdf:FileReference>000000B00000000T00000000</ecdf:FileReference>
<ecdf:eCDFFileVersion>aaaa</ecdf:eCDFFileVersion>
<ecdf:Interface>a</ecdf:Interface>
<ecdf:Agent>
    <ecdf:MatrNbr>String</ecdf:MatrNbr>
    <ecdf:RCSNbr>String</ecdf:RCSNbr>
    <ecdf:VATNbr>String</ecdf:VATNbr>
</ecdf:Agent>
<ecdf:Declarations>
    <ecdf:Declarer>
        <ecdf:MatrNbr>String</ecdf:MatrNbr>
        <ecdf:RCSNbr>String</ecdf:RCSNbr>
        <ecdf:VATNbr>String</ecdf:VATNbr>
        <ecdf:Declaration language="FR" type="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" model="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">
            <ecdf:Year>2000</ecdf:Year>
            <ecdf:Period>0</ecdf:Period>
            <ecdf:FormData>
                <NumericField id="233">1</NumericField>
                <NumericField id="234">1</NumericField>
                <TextField id="235">31</TextField>
                <TextField id="236">12</TextField>
                <NumericField id="012">5010,00</NumericField>
                <Choice id="204">1</Choice>
                <Choice id="205">0</Choice>
                <NumericField id="414">90,00</NumericField>
                <NumericField id="415">300,00</NumericField>
                <ecdf:Table>
                    <ecdf:Line num="2">
                        <NumericField id="01">01/01/2012</NumericField>
                        <NumericField id="02">31/12/2012</NumericField>
                        <TextField id="03">EUR</TextField>
                        <TextField id="639">54606,08</TextField>
                        <Choice id="640">0</Choice>
                    </ecdf:Line>
                </ecdf:Table>
            </ecdf:FormData>
        </ecdf:Declaration>
    </ecdf:Declarer>
</ecdf:Declarations>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Define a variable `$name` using `xsl:choose`. Then use `xsl:element` to create an element named $name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="FormDataElement">
<xsl:variable name="outputElementName">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(., 'NUMERIC')">NumericField</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(., 'TEXT')">TextField</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(., 'CHOICE')">Choice</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><!-- Fail fast --></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="{$outputElementName}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```